# Do conformal mappings other than the Mobius transformations preserve symmetry?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Linear fractional transformations preserve symmetric points, e.g., if the real axis in the z-plane gets mapped to the imaginary axis in the w-plane, then points symmetric with respect to the real axis get mapped to points that are again symmetric - with respect to the imaginary axis, which is the image of the real line.

Does such a useful symmetry argument exist for non-LFTs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any meromorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ (not necessarily LFT) that maps the real axis to the imaginary axis, then consider $g(x) = f(x)/i$, which maps the real axis onto itself.  Then consider $h(x)=\overline{g(\overline{x})}$, which is another meromorphic function that agrees with $g$ on the whole real axis.  It follows that $h$ must equal $g$ everywhere.  Why: [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) (refer to "An Improvement"). [**Edit:** The theorem as stated in the link applies to holomorphic functions, not meromorphic functions.  To get it for meromorphic functions: given any desired point $x$, you can find some connected open set $U$ containing $x$ and intersecting the real axis and avoiding all the poles of $g$ and $h$, and then you can apply the holomorphic version of the theorem on $U$ to deduce that $g(x) = h(x)$.  I had originally included this explanation in my answer (honest!), but I inadvertently deleted it.]

Now we know $f(x)/i = \overline{f(\overline{x})/i}$, i.e., $f(\overline{x}) = -\overline{f(x)}$, from which your symmetry property follows.

**TL;DR:** Any meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ that maps the real axis to the imaginary axis has the same symmetry property.

Comment: Hi @DarshRanjan, I don't think this quite works?  For two points to be symmetric w.r.t. the imaginary axis in the w-plane, if one point is u+iv, then the symmetric point is -u+iv.  Is that what your equation implies?  I feel like it's implying that the symmetric point is -u-iv; that would be symmetry about the origin. Thanks,

Comment: If $x=a+ib$ and $f(x)=c+id$, then $\overline{x} = a-ib$ (the reflection of $x$ over the real axis), and $-\overline{f(x)}=-(c-id)=-c+id$ (the reflection of $f(x)$ over the imaginary axis).

Comment: Ah, very cool - thanks so much @darshranjan :-)

Comment: If the real line were mapped to a circle, will symmetric points wrt the real line again be symmetric in the w-plane wrt the circle?  This is true for LFTs; just wondering whether it's also true for any meromorphic function (that sends the real line to a circle.). Thanks,

Comment: ... I'm wondering whether we got lucky with straight lines mapping to straight lines.  If the transformation isn't linear, I would guess the symmetry property doesn't always hold.  It's very memorable when Ahlfors states the symmetry properties of LFTs in his book, but I don't recall such a thing was ever claimed for other conformal mappings...so, I'm just wondering.  Thanks,

Comment: Regarding mapping the real line to a circle (WLOG, the unit circle): instead of $g(x) = f(x)/i$, define $g(x) = (f(x)+i)/(if(x)+1)$, which again maps the real line to itself.  Going through the rest of the argument and modifying the algebra appropriately, you can deduce that $f(\overline{x}) = 1/\overline{f(x)}$, so the answer to your question is "yes" if "symmetric wrt the unit circle" is defined by the relation $z\sim 1/\overline{z}$.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much for your follow-up answers, @DarshRanjan :-)